# Replacing consecutive repeating pattern using regex

Tags: regex

I want to replace consecutive repeating pattern with just a single pattern. For example:

1. ABABABABB -> ABB
2. AAACCC -> AC
3. AABAAC -> ABAC

How can I achieve this using regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following regex finds all matches with a repeating pattern in them:

```
(.+?)\1+
```

Working example can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/noOaHJ/1. Also, regex is just a tool to find patterns- how you use it for actual replacement depends on the language you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have tried what you suggested. It will replace all occurrences of the same pattern. What I want is that it should change only consecutive patterns. For example: ABABABABBDAB should be changed into ABBDAB.

Comment: as i said, regex can only help you to find patterns- if you play with the link i gave, you'll see that the regex i gave works fine. you have problems in the code that uses this regex for actual replacing.

Comment: this question, as is, is answered i think. for replacing, you should raise another question for replacing the regex pattern. that is because the answer to that will depend on the language you are using

Comment: I am using Java for my code. `temp = temp.replaceAll("(.+?)\\1+", "(?:$1)+")`